# Arduino IDE Auto Format Error

Tags: ide, java

Whenever I try to format a sketch in the IDE (1.8.19) I get this output in the terminal:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.String cc.arduino.packages.formatter.AStyleInterface.AStyleMain(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
          at cc.arduino.packages.formatter.AStyleInterface.AStyleMain(Native Method)
          at cc.arduino.packages.formatter.AStyle.run(AStyle.java:80)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
          at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
          at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

...And formatting fails.

I can use astyle from the command line (linux mint) and it works well.

Guessing that some basic package was missing, or corrupted, I reinstalled Arduino, but the issue remained.

I don't precisely recall any specific changes made to my system prior to encountering this behavior, as it's been like this for at least 8 or 9 months now. I hadn't used Arduino for some time up until that point and it may have been a fresh instal.

Since I just started a new project for a buddy of mine and encountered the bug again I decided maybe it was time to see about a better solution.

Any help troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/11728 might be similar (from package manager it didn't work, downloaded from arduino.cc worked)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the version from https://www.arduino.cc/en/software does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled the first line of stack trace and found similar [issue on github](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/11728) (but for SUSE linux). In this issue the Arduino IDE was installed by system package manager and after downloading latest package from arduino.cc/en/software it started working.

In general Arduino IDE linux packages are somehow problematic (as far as I know Ubuntu has still version around 1.0.6) and it's better to use latest version directly from arduino.cc

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a version issue, maybe something in the dependencies... I installed from the Ubuntu Jammy package, and got Arduino 1.8.19, which yielded the error in the original post, on multiple installations. Then I installed that same version from the Arduino site and it worked fine.